# If $f$ is entire and $f \circ (\_)^{-1}$ has a pole at $z = 0$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering if somebody could help me finish off the proof of this statement; I'm not sure if my approach can be salvaged, but here's what I've got so far:

Since $f \circ (\_)^{-1}$ has a pole at $z=0$, we can write

$(f \circ (\_)^{-1})(z) = P(z) + G(z)$, where P is the "principal part" (this is the term used in my book, which hasn't at this point, mentioned anything about Laurent series, so I'm trying not use that stuff in my proof) of $f \circ (\_)^{-1}$, and $G$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$. But then

$f(z) = (f \circ (\_)^{-1})(z^{-1}) = P(z^{-1}) + G(z^{-1})= (P \circ (\_)^{-1})(z) + (G \circ (\_)^{-1})(z)$, where $f$ is entire and $P \circ (\_)^{-1}$ is actually a polynomial. Thus $G \circ (\_)^{-1} = f - P \circ (\_)^{-1}$ is entire, and if I can just show that it is bounded, I get the desired claim, by Liouville's theorem.

However, I'm not sure how to get boundedness. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You know that $G$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$. In particular, $G$ is bounded on $\{z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\}$ for some $r > 0$. That means $G\circ (\_)^{-1}$ is bounded on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \geqslant r^{-1}\}$. But $G\circ (\_)^{-1}$ is also bounded on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r^{-1}\}$, since that set is compact.

Comment: Is $(\_)^{-1}$ the map $x\mapsto \frac{1}x$?